# Will handlers to an event raised inside a lock execute outside the lock?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Will handlers to an event raised inside a lock execute outside the lock? When are the handlers iterated over, immediately after the method that raises the event is completed?

Comment: give more details, or show us your code

Comment: Do you have race conditions with calling events and adding/removing event handlers at the same time?

Comment: I'm just studying how locks behave, and obviously my thought process could not continue with this issue in question. I will post subsequent questions if I have, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are just delegates and will be executed immediately inside the `lock`.

Answer (score 1):

If you rise events synchronously, the same thread executes code of event handlers, and only after execution it returns to start point and exists from lock block